# What do wizards in Muggle wheelchairs do if they go to Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter

Hogwarts is definitely not wheelchair-friendly. So what do wizards in Muggle wheelchairs do if they go to Hogwarts?

Comment: I don't know for certain, but do we know that wizards use Muggle wheelchairs (as opposed to floating wizard chairs or something)?

Comment: The boring answer is probably that if someone who would otherwise use a wheelchair needed to get from floor to floor in Hogwarts, they'd probably use some object enchanted with permanent Levitation Charm.

Comment: There are no disabled students. Simples

Comment: Surely a broomstick is for all intents and purposes a full mobility transportation device

Answer (score 9):

There's definitely evidence that some wizards use a wheelchair. In *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child* I believe Amos Diggory uses a wheelchair in his old age. He obviously wouldn't face the same limitations as an elderly wheelchair bound Muggle however, since his ability to perform magic wasn't hindered.

However, specific disabilities that force someone to reside in a wheelchair (such as muscular dystrophy or motor neurone disease) seem to be absent from the wizarding world. This could mean one of two things.

## Wizards don't get disabilities from birth

Genetic conditions (except for poor eyesight) aren't present in the wizarding world. Everyone can walk and interact fairly easily within their quite dated world, showing no signs of mental or physical ill health caused by a genetic defect. A magical illness or disability caused by magic can affect a wizard however. Rowling has addressed this in an article on Pottermore.

> I decided that, broadly speaking, wizards would have the power to correct or override 'mundane' nature, but not 'magical' nature. Therefore, a wizard could catch anything a Muggle might catch, but he could cure all of it; he would also comfortably survive a scorpion sting that might kill a Muggle, whereas he might die if bitten by a Venomous Tentacula. Similarly, bones broken in non-magical accidents such as falls or fist fights can be mended by magic, but the consequences of curses or backfiring magic could be serious, permanent or life-threatening. This is the reason Gilderoy Lockhart, victim of his own mangled Memory Charm, has permanent amnesia, why the poor Longbottoms remain permanently damaged by magical torture, and why Mad-Eye Moody had to resort to a wooden leg and a magical eye when the originals were irreparably damaged in a wizards' battle; Luna Lovegood's mother, Pandora, died when one of her own experimental spells went wrong, and Bill Weasley is irreversibly scarred after meeting with Fenrir Greyback.
>
> <sub>***Illness and Disability*** **by J.K. Rowling, Pottermore**</sub>

So if a wizard gets a disability later in life, such as losing a leg, and that disability is the result of a magical accident, then they're stuck with it. Still doesn't address the issue of those with a disability from birth though. There's a popular theory that the genes associated with magic correct any faulty genes in a developing foetus, meaning no wizard is ever born with a mental or physical disability, but this isn't confirmed in canon just fan speculation. From Rowling's article, there's a second possibility.

## Wizards can fix non-magical disabilities

From Rowling's article, it could be interpreted that disabilities humans can have from birth are in the 'mundane' category, and as such are completely curable through various spells and potions. Furthermore, it would seem that any injury a wizard sustains that isn't magical in nature could be cured, even if it would render a Muggle disabled. Again, eyesight is potentially a notable exception to this, although maybe it can be fixed but, like a lot of Muggles, wizards don't really mind wearing glasses.

## To Conclude

The Hogwarts we see is from the perspective of an able bodied person, Harry, so we aren't privy to any disabled access features it might have. Like most buildings built about 1000 years ago, people didn't accommodate for the disabled as they weren't really part of society, so it probably didn't feature any back in the day. However, as Muggle society has learned to value all life equally and accommodate for the less able among us, wizarding society probably has as well. Hogwarts Castle itself is magical, and can change its architecture, so there may well be plenty of disabled access should a student or staff member join who can't manage the 142 staircases and death slide to the Chamber of Secrets. Failing that, you can enchant inanimate objects to do just about anything, so a wheelchair that can do stairs probably isn't a stretch too far in a world of witches and wizards.

Answer (score 1):

Wizards may not need wheelchairs.

They seem to be able to repair non-fatal injuries, as Harry's arm was repaired after he broke it at Quidditch.

Comment: The general rule, as stated by Rowling herself, is that magic can deal with any non-magical health issues, but is stymied by some magical ones. So some witches and wizards still need accessibility aids, like Moody's walking stick, artificial leg, and magical eye.

Comment: There's also possibly personal preference to consider (some people prefer glasses to contacts or LASIK, say).

Comment: @Adamant though shattered spine might be much more difficult to heal than a broken arm, and magic is not omnipotent after all. Did Rowling address rather critical yet non-magical health issues as well?

Comment: @NikitaNeganov - See the wiki on [Skele-gro](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Skele-Gro) - There is a reference to a Quidditch player that broke "most of the bones in his body" being healed by skelegro.One would assume that a collision with the ground at 60mph would break at least a few of the bones in the spine. :)